# Netty's hostname verification support for JDK 1.6

Tags: java, netty

Does netty have any libraries to do host name verification when using JDK 6? The default sun jdk trust manager doesn't support hostname verification.

Answer (score 0):

Nettys SslHandler just use a SslEngine. So no special handling build in.